# Threading mechanism for long process that updates different UI components

Tags: java, swing

I have long process that do multiple non similar steps and at the end of each step it updates different UI component in the interface, I tried `SwingWorker` but the mechanism seems suitable for publishing similar repetitive results, with `Thread` and `SwingUtilities` it works but I want to know if there is any another threading mechanism that play well with EDT.

Comment: No, generally speaking `SwingWorker` is your best bet.  You're right in the fact that it does work well with repeated iterations, but it also works well with start->end->notify workflows or non-regular interval updates as well.  At the end of the day, `SwingUtiltiies.invokeLater` is the lowest level interaction you have to seed updates to back to the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks, I posted this question because I feel that SwingUtiltiies.invokeLater is abused from within running thread, so I thought it could have an impact on performance

Comment: `SwingUtiltiies.invokeLater` can be easily abused, leading to thread starvation issues of the EDT, so you need to be careful with how you use it.  `SwingWorker`, for example, consolidates many of it's calls, so rather the doing individual updates to the EDT, it can do batch updates instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the info :) , I will try to reorder and split the work then adapt SwingWorker to execute suitable parts and see if any gain is added.